# Scale element based on font size

Tags: css

I'm styling labels with css and I'm trying to scale them depending on the font size used inside it.

The goal here is to reduce the overall size but keep the proportions just like `tranform: scale` does but without reducing the quality.

For example:

With a font size of `1em`
[image]

and with a font size of `0.5em`
[image]

Any idea on how to achieve that ?

Thanks !

Comment: try to specify all the property using em then

Comment: Check this post maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container

Comment: Please could you create a [mcve] showing your current code

Comment: Why are you giving no feedback?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to style the labels to the size depending on your font-size, you should use padding for the space around it, so the label's size is depending on your font-size.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly.

Basically you want to set a font-size for a label and then automatically adjust the font-size for the others labels ? If so... the simplest way to do that is to use `em` for each label of the dependency label.

```
<label>
  Label A
  <label>
    Label B
      <label>
        Label C
          <label>
            Label D
           </label>
      <label>
    </label>
</label>
```

CSS

```
label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
}
label > label {
  font-size: .9em;
}
```

[codepen source here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NYQvbK)

Comment: This is really interesting but not really what I'm trying to achieve. What I want to do is to 'scale' all aspect of the label based on the font-size of the text inside

Comment: @ThéoChampion what about this anwser [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container?noredirect=1&lq=1) ?? and by meaning `all aspect of the label` you mean the element for each label individual ??